# Partition given string using regex

Tags: python, regex

Trying to break the string into 2 parts.

```py
#Need to get 'I1234' and 'I56/I78'
name1 = 'I1234/I56/I78'

#Need to get '\I1234 ' and 'I56/I78'
name2 = '\I1234 /I56/I78'      

#Need to get '\I1234 ' and '\I56 /I78'
name3 = '\I1234 /\I56 /I78'

#Need to get '\1234 ' and '\I56 /\I78 '
name4 = '\I1234 /\I56 /\I78 '
```

I tried this,  and it worked:

```py
pat_a = re.compile(r'(.+)(/)(.+)')

Is there a better way ?

result = re.findall(pat_a, name2[::-1])
```

### EDIT

There are more complicated strings possible, for example:

```
\I78_[0]/abcd_/efg_ /I1234/I56
```

Comment: Is there a reason for negative vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe because your description isn't too clear. "Trying to break the string into 2 parts." doesn't tell us much about where in the string you're trying to break, or the pattern you're trying to set.

Comment: What's the proper split for **\I78_[0]/abcd_/efg_ /I1234/I56**?

Comment: @Dragonfly what is the required output for the more complicated string? I had this in my answer -- ['\I78_[0]', 'abcd_/efg_ /I1234/I56'] -- but is that right?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if its better, but you can use `partition` or `split` with *maxsplit=1* given to avoid the `re` module import:

```
print('I1234/I56/I78'.partition("/"))   # ('I1234', '/', 'I56/I78')

print('I1234/I56/I78'.split("/",1))     # ['I1234', 'I56/I78']
```

For `partition` you would need to look at the 0th and 2nd index of the tuple:

```
first, _ , last = 'I1234/I56/I78'.partition("/")
```

Doku:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

---

Full example:

```
name1 = 'I1234/I56/I78' 
name2 = '\I1234 /I56/I78'       
name3 = '\I1234 /\I56 /I78' 
name4 = '\I1234 /\I56 /\I78 '

for n in [name1,name2,name3,name4]:
    print(n.partition("/"))   # ('I1234', '/', 'I56/I78')
    print(n.split("/",1))     # ['I1234', 'I56/I78']
```

Output (backslashes are escaped - thats why they are doubled up):

```
('I1234', '/', 'I56/I78')           # using partition
['I1234', 'I56/I78']                # using split

('\\I1234 ', '/', 'I56/I78')        # partition
['\\I1234 ', 'I56/I78']             # split .. etc.

('\\I1234 ', '/', '\\I56 /I78')
['\\I1234 ', '\\I56 /I78']

('\\I1234 ', '/', '\\I56 /\\I78 ')
['\\I1234 ', '\\I56 /\\I78 ']
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I have a few more corner cases. I have edited my question.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but I'd suggest splitting up your two solutions, and showing them separately.  Also, I'd go ahead and grab the 1st and 3rd components of the result of 'partition', and print those, so you show how to get the desired result in each case.  As it is, your answer is a bit confusing. - I do like you showing two alternatives.

Comment: @Steve - thats why I seperated the solutions _on top_ and also showed how top split them via decomposition. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @PatrickArtner - yeah, no biggie.  I just think being able to view both the code and the output as two unique examples would be clearer.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works for the first 4 strings, but not for the more complicated string.

Comment: @Dragonfly what is the required output for the more complicated string? I had this ['\I78_[0]',  'abcd_/efg_ /I1234/I56'], but is that right?

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses `string.split`, which seems to be the cleanest method over regex.  I looked at using `string.partition`, but it produces a `tuple`, which requires index splitting. Plus the output related to `string.partition` doesn't give the output that you requested.

This first example takes a single string and outputs a pair of strings based on your split request.

```
# Need to get '\I1234 ' and '\I56 /I78'
name3 = '\I1234 /\I56 /I78'

# The input name (name3) can be change in a for loop linked to your input. 
split_input = name3.split('/', 1) # maxsplit=1
print (split_input)
# outputs 
#####################################################################
# NOTE: the escaped backslashes, which doesn't match your requirement. 
#####################################################################
['\\I1234 ', '\\I56 /I78']
```

The original output above created escaped backslashes, so this code removes them.

```
# Need to get '\I1234 ' and '\I56 /I78'
name3 = '\I1234 /\I56 /I78'

# The input name (name3) can be change in a for loop linked to your input. 
split_input = str(name3.split('/', 1)).encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
print (split_input)
# outputs 
['\I1234 ', '\I56 /I78'] # Do you need that trailing space?
```

I'm ***not sure*** where your input values are originally coming from (e.g., file, website, etc.), so I added the ones from your question to a list for faster testing. The next example use list comprehension and string.split.

```
my_strings = ['I1234/I56/I78', '\I1234 /I56/I78', '\I1234 /\I56 /I78', '\I1234 /\I56 /\I78', '\I78_[0]/abcd_/efg_ /I1234/I56']

# Uses list comprehension and string.split to split the elements in your strings
split_input = [x.split('/', 1) for x in my_strings]

# The original output created escaped backslashes, so this code removes them.
decode_output = (str(split_input).encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape'))

print (decode_output)
# outputs 
[['I1234', 'I56/I78'], ['\I1234 ', 'I56/I78'], ['\I1234 ', '\I56 /I78'], ['\I1234 ', '\I56 /\I78'], ['\I78_[0]', 'abcd_/efg_ /I1234/I56']]
```

Comment: Why are you starting with a totally different input? Instead of strings you use lists of lists of strings that are already split up. Also why the shenanigangs with escaped backslashes and splitting the `str()` representation fo your `split_input`? This is an answer for a totally different question ...

Comment: After reviewing my answer, I noted that I posted the output of the code as the input values.  I have corrected that mistake.  Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: I added the input values in the OP's question to a list, so that I could process them faster. I also did this because I don't know where the input values will come from and how the OP needs to output them, beyond printing them. I updated my answer to use the OP's input exactly as it was provided.